# Задача про декораторы питон

Tags: python

Как написать декоратора который перед выполнением функции ждет несколько секунд?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: мне нужно написать функцию которая постоянно проверяет, изменились ли данные на веб-странице или её код.И нужно написать декоратор который перед выполнением этой функции ждет несколько секунд.Я не понимаю как это сделать

Answer (score 3):

```
import time

def waiting(fnc):
    time.sleep(4)
    fnc()

@waiting
def get_data():
    print('Идет анализ данных')
```

Кажется, вы вообще не пытались решить проблему

Comment: И вы решили проблему за автора вопроса. Очень педагогично.

Comment: @strawdog кто-то бы все равно решил)